# How to reference to a response object with swagger?

Tags: api, swagger

I can do this:

```
parameters:
  avatarSizeParam:
    name: size
    in: query
    description: Size of avatar.
    enum: [32, 64]
    required: false
    type: integer
    format: int32

paths:
  /my/path/avatar:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/avatarSizeParam'
```

Good. Swagger defines a `parameters` key where you can define `Parameter Objects` to be
reused. It also defines a `responses` key, where you can define `Response Objects` like
so:

```
responses:
  notFoundResponse:
    description: Entity not found.
    schema:
      $ref: '#/definitions/schema404'
```

So I assumed I could expand my previous path definition to the following

```
paths:
  /my/path/avatar:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/avatarSizeParam'
      responses:
        - $ref: '#/responses/notFound'
```

This doesn't seem to work however. I went back to [the spec](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#operationObject) for an `Operations Object` and noticed that `parameters` can be a Reference Object, but `responses` cannot.

[image: Operation Object definiton (partial)]

What is the point of allowing a Responses Definitions Object (`responses` on the top-most level) if
you can't reference the items there? Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you see [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#patterned-fields-3), you have to define HTTP Status Code as a key, then the correct syntax is:

```
paths:
  /my/path/avatar:
    get:
      parameters:
        - $ref: '#/parameters/avatarSizeParam'
      responses:
        404:
          $ref: '#/responses/notFound'
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah this makes lots of sense. Forgot `responses` was an object and not an array hahah